# Is there a "hardware reset" for the Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, power-on

I have had my Samsung Galaxy S for less than a year, and never did anything like rooting it. Just normal use.

About 60 minutes ago I opened from it's "sleep" state to check a web page and left it on my desk where it went to "sleep".

Now about 10 minutes ago, I tried to open it again, but it's dead. Touching the screen doesn't bring up anything. I press and hold the power button which doesn't do anything. I don't remember the battery being low, but I plugged it in anyway.

The recharge screen doesn't come up and it still won't start even with the power cord plugged in.

What can I do ? Is there some kind of hardware reset I can do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you wait some time after the power cord was pluged in? It is normal that this takes some time to show the charging screen *if the battery is not charged at all*.

For a full factory reset (that is the most reset that can be done by the Galaxy S), you want to boot into recovery mode by powering off the device, and then booting it by holding down the **Volume Up + Home + Power** keys. A menu should appear that offers the "Factory Reset" option.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the phone simply froze up. Try taking out the battery, putting it back in, and then press the Power button to start it.